# IBM ACE Specified Character is not supported Error

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ibm-integration-bus

Recently i installed IBM ACE 12.0.6.0 on Windows 10, and when i try to execute any command in IBM ACE Console this error output:

```
`C:\Program Files\IBM\ACE\12.0.6.0>mqsilist
WARNING: Specified charset is not supported, UTF-8 is used for default charset
Exception in thread "main" java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java/lang/J9VMInternals.ensureError (J9VMInternals.java:145)
        at java/lang/J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure (J9VMInternals.java:134)
        at com/ibm/jvm/io/LocalizedInputStream.getInputStream (LocalizedInputStream.java:332)
        at java/io/InputStreamReader.<init> (InputStreamReader.java:87)
        at java/io/FileReader.<init> (FileReader.java:83)
        at sun/misc/MetaIndex.registerDirectory (MetaIndex.java:177)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run (Launcher.java:171)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run (Launcher.java:166)
        at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:747)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader.createExtClassLoader (Launcher.java:165)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader (Launcher.java:152)
        at sun/misc/Launcher.<init> (Launcher.java:82)
        at sun/misc/Launcher.<clinit> (Launcher.java:68)
        at java/lang/ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders (ClassLoader.java:196)
        at java/lang/Thread.initialize (Thread.java:411)
        at java/lang/Thread.<init> (Thread.java:158)
java/nio/charset/UnsupportedCharsetException: MS65001
        at java/nio/charset/Charset.forName (Charset.java:579)
        at com/ibm/jvm/io/ConsoleInputStream.<clinit> (ConsoleInputStream.java:100)
        at com/ibm/jvm/io/LocalizedInputStream.getInputStream (LocalizedInputStream.java:332)
        at java/io/InputStreamReader.<init> (InputStreamReader.java:87)
        at java/io/FileReader.<init> (FileReader.java:83)
        at sun/misc/MetaIndex.registerDirectory (MetaIndex.java:177)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run (Launcher.java:171)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader$1.run (Launcher.java:166)
        at java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:747)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader.createExtClassLoader (Launcher.java:165)
        at sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader.getExtClassLoader (Launcher.java:152)
        at sun/misc/Launcher.<init> (Launcher.java:82)
        at sun/misc/Launcher.<clinit> (Launcher.java:68)
        at java/lang/ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaders (ClassLoader.java:196)
        at java/lang/Thread.initialize (Thread.java:411)
        at java/lang/Thread.<init> (Thread.java:158)`
```

I check the current encoding charset

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

And in Region section in Control Panel System Locale is set English(United States). I'm from Serbia if that's important.

I think this is encoding and Java problem, but i don't know how to change default charset.

Comment: mqsilist seems to me to be a command that starts the java virtual machine . This is running with the modern default encoding of UTF-8. You probably need to tell it to use *your* encoding,  which is Windows-1252

Comment: How should i do that?

Comment: I can't tell you I'm afraid. Isn't ACE a commercial product though? Support should be dealing with it if so

Comment: What do you think, maybe i should change default encoding, from Windows 1252 to UTF-8, is that going to make any harm to other applications running on Windows?

Comment: @Boro Nobody else can tell you whether changing the default encoding on your machine is going to affect other applications - only you can know that. But yes, it is certainly possible, and changing it will impact all user accounts, not just the one you normally use.

Comment: This is the most important information in the stack trace: `UnsupportedCharsetException: MS65001`. Something is trying to use a charset named **MS65001**, which doesn't exist. Can you find any references to **MS65001** in your environment?